# When a page is edited where does the markup come from?

Tags: 2007, markup

When the edit page link is clicked (for a publishing site on MOSS 2007) there is additional markup. Where does this come from? I would like to modify a script that is there.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about in SharePoint designer? What mark-up are you referring to? The mark-up in SPD is a combination of master page, page layout, publishing field controls, control templates and web parts.

Comment: When you look at the html for a rendered page it's roughly the same as the page when viewed using sharepoint designer. But when the page is being edited and the html is viewed there are additional scripts etc. Where do these come from?